# Java Not greater than certain value

Tags: java, range, modulus

I just have a simple question. In Java, we know that the remainder of  (y%x) can't be greater than x itself. Thus, we could hypothetically set all numbers less than a certain value of x, say 100. Yet what would be the opposite of this? What if we wanted to set all numbers above a certain value, say 20, to have a range [20,100]?

I was thinking that we could subtract 20 from both sides to have the range [0,80], and then take the modulus of 80, and then add 20 to it.

Am I right in believing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Or take a value in the range [0, 80] and add 20 to the result. Then you have a value in the range [20, 100]. What range do you want to have at the end?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math and number algorithms that are not specific to programming nor to Java specifically

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I was hoping to have a value in the range [20,100], but I was unsure how to make all values greater than 20.

Comment: @ControlAltDel, this has to do with modulus. That's in java.

Comment: @user4253715: Java also has strings. Doesn't mean we'll help people with learning English either.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Why do you have to be so rude about it? I understand that this question wasn't exactly how it should have been formatted. But I honestly don't understand your abrasive response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Random` class includes [`nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) which (per the Javadoc) *Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed `int` value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.* So, 0-80 is

```
Random rand = new Random();
int v = rand.nextInt(81);
```

If you want it in the ragne 20-100 that would be

```
int v = rand.nextInt(81) + 20;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ElliotFrish, this is very helpful! I really appreciate your simple answer and willingness to help.

Answer (score 0):

How can the remainder be greater that the divisor ? In other words you division is not complete.

If you want to of from 20-80 you can simple do

```
int i = 20 + randomInteger % 80;
```

This will be in the range of 20 -100.

Comment: Okay, but if you take the mod of 80, then all randomIntegers won't be greater than 80. But then when you add 20, they could be, right?

Comment: the number would be between 0-79 when you add 20 the bounds would be 20-99 ...